# i have problem for setting java environment in windows

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, buildship

I have Gradle build like this

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'test.build'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web-services'
    implementation 'org.springframework.session:spring-session-core'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.oracle.database.jdbc:ojdbc8'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

and here my application

```
package test.build.test;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

When I build the project, I see there is an error like in this picture:

[image: Eclipse code editor showing errors in provided code]

What is the issue? Is there any error in my Gradle build file?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow ! From the image provided, it seems you're using Eclipse to develop your project. How did you import the project? Is the project configured as Gradle project? Are you able to build the project from the command line (`gradlew.bat build` (CMD), `.\gradlew.bat build` (PowerShell))?

Comment: yes i build using eclipse why that is an error ?

Comment: Eclipse is okay, no worries. Are you able to build the project from the command line? How did you import the project into Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have a missing dependency. Try adding the following dependency:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
```

Comment: Not very likely. The build file provided looks like it has been generated from [start.spring.io](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.4.2.RELEASE&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=11&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web,oracle,web-services,data-rest,session,lombok) which doesn't list `spring-boot-starter` as dependency as well.